Transforming count data for NMDS?
I am looking at species count data. Due to large counts of certain species, I initially fourth root transformed the data. I am using Bray-Curtis distance measurement.
However when using vegan::metaMDS, the stress value for the data is a little over 0.2 It's not much(0.21), but I understand that stress values greater than 0.2 are suspicious at best. However when i use non-transformed data, the stress is less than 0.2, so I am tempted to use the non-transformed data.
My concern is wether this will than impact species scores when plotting if NMDS is using untransformed data, and other tests are using a transformed version such as PERMANOVA or ANOSIM. Is using untransformed data for NMDS even alright? Most examples always use counts transformed in some way. Will this cause problems comparing other multivariate tests?

Select data transforms and the kind of distance on your field, theoretic and logical considerations, and not on a fit criterion such as stress of MDS.

"understand that stress values greater than 0.2 are suspicious at best" I have done a lot of MDS on species data, and I've rarely seen stress values of < 0.15. 0.2ish seems normal to me. Ecological data is very messy. I wouldn't be too fussed.

One useful way to approach transform species data from a perspective of "what do I want to know". For example, if you have count data which is dominated by high counts of common, non threatened species, and you don't really care about what happens to them, then I would not suggest using untransformed data as the distances will be dominated by them. If you care about rare species, then you might go towards something like richness instead of counts. And so on

Note that NMDS does not have a concept of "species scores". The vegan R-package post-hoc superimposes weighted average scores, I think, but there are (AFAIK) few guarantees that these make a lot of sense. If you are interested in the species' locations on an axis, you might be better suited by using methods that explicitly include species scores, such as C(C)A or the model-based ordination methods suggested by Diogo in his answer. These also keep you from having to consider a transformation for count data, since model-based ordination methods function without using distances.

In this case I'd highly recommend you to switch to model-based unconstrained ordination techniques, such as the ones implemented in the R packages gllvm, ecoCopula and the like. You could use an explicit probability distribution and also diagnose the model residuals using diagnostic plots.

I'll add a note as to address OPs question; model-based ordination methods function without the specification of distance measures, so that it avoids the issue of "transformation" or specification of a distance measure. In place, as Diogo writes, it requires specification or a distribution. Fortunately, for count data, there are only a few suitable alternatives (e.g., Poisson, negative-binomial).
